# Why is 'signing' your question generally frowned upon?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, signature

I've 'signed' several of my questions (across the SE platform) like so:

```
Thanks for any help or insights, I appreciate it!
```

or something akin that, sometimes along with my name. My reasoning behind this is that someone is taking a fairly significant chunk of time to help me out, and I want to let them know I really do appreciate it (this feeling is compounded by the fact that I'm relatively inexperienced, so it's not often I can give back by answering questions). However, more often than not, someone edits this out. Not that I really have any problem with it, I'm just wondering what the reasoning behind it is.

Comment: Downvotes here **DO NOT** mean there is something wrong with your question, they mean that a user does not agree with your idea. I dont agree that signatures should be allowed but I appreciate you coming to ask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Signatures are not allowed, think of the useless noise added by every user adding an extra one line signature. Your signature is your little name and link in the corner.

If you want to thank someone upvote great answers and accept the one that solves the issue. This is the built in site reward.